How to connect to remote database through remote server to local device?
Let's say I have two server A and B.
Server A is open to public.
Server B is only allow connection from server A.
My MySQL database is located on server B.
From my local machine, how to I connect my DBeaver / DataGrip to database which is located at server B? I have ssh credentials to server A.

As mentioned by @user1191247, Connect to remote db with ssh tunneling in DBeaver answer my question.
Here's the details.



As you said, No local connection can be made to Server B, because it allows traffic only from Server A
Alternatively you can use mysql terminal client using ssh
Also you can use phpMyAdmin in Server A, if Server A allows HTTP connection from your local machine
